# Difficult and unusual probability problem, how to solve?

Tags: probability, analysis, statistics, limits

> Let $n_i$ be the $i$'th randomly chosen element from $\mathbb N$ with replacements. All elements have probability greater than zero of being chosen. After a number of trials $k$, the probability that $\sum_i^k n_i=x$ is $P(x)$. What are the conditions for $\lim_{x\to\infty}P(x)$ to exist and what does it evaluate to?

I flipped through my texts and now I think I can't solve this one, unless there is some trick.

My problem is maybe that I don't know how to figure out the distribution of $\sum_i^k n_i$. Maybe the problem can be solved without it. I don't know.

Can you help me solve problem?

Comment: Whoops, I orally relay this problem from what I hear. It isn't equiprobable. It's probability greater than zero, that's all.

Comment: Hint: consider the case $k=1$. What's the answer?  (The answer in the general case is obtained in a similar manner and relies on this one.)

Answer (score 1):

You can not draw uniform random variables in $\mathbb N$. Where do you get this problem from?

Comment: Tutoring a high school student, who asked me this question. I relay question badly, I'm sorry.

Comment: OK then no harm done :). You know that $\sum_{x \in \mathbb N} P(x) = 1$, so the limit as $x \to \infty$ is zero.